# How to pass an array into SpEL expression within JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-el

Am trying to use SpEL to call method on a service class, eg:

```
<spring:eval expression="@securityService.hasPermissionToAllArray('${data.regionsArray}')" />
```

Where data is an object in the request scope, and it has a method as follows:

```
public String[] getRegionsArray() {
    List<String> regions = new ArrayList<String>();
    regions.add("aaa");
    regions.add("bbb");
    return regions.toArray(new String[]{});
}
```

And the securityService has this method defined:

```
public boolean hasPermissionToAllArray(String []regions) {
    logger.warn("size={} regions='{}' regions[0]={}", regions.length, regions, regions[0]);
    return true;
}
```

Here is the output from the logger:

```
size=1 regions='[[Ljava.lang.String;@13299648]' regions[0]=[Ljava.lang.String;@13299648
```

So it seems like the returned value from getRegionsArray() is being converted into a string, and then passed to hasPermissionToAllArray() as the first element of the array.

If I convert the array value to a string as follows, it works:

```
        <c:set var="r" value="${fn:join(data.regionsArray, ',')}" />
        <spring:eval expression="@securityService.hasPermissionToAllArray('${r}')" />
```

Here is the log output:

```
size=2 regions='[aaa, bbb]' regions[0]=aaa
```

But, obviously this is not ideal.

NOTE: have tried using List's instead of arrays, with the same outcome.

Comment: Did you try `<spring:eval expression="@securityService.hasPermissionToAllArray(${data.regionsArray})" />`?

Answer (score 2):

In a JSP, an expression like `${something}` will be resolved by the EL resolver regardless of where it is. It is not processed by Spring's Expression Language. Therefore, the `expression` will always resolve to something like

```
@securityService.hasPermissionToAllArray('[Ljava.lang.String;@56165397')
```

regardless of the quotes.

Fortunately, you can access the request (and other scopes) attributes with `requestScope`.

So change your `expression` to the following

```
<spring:eval expression="@driver.hasPermissionToAllArray(requestScope.data.regionsArray)" />
```

or simply

```
<spring:eval expression="@driver.hasPermissionToAllArray(data.regionsArray)" />
```

if the attribute might be in any of the page, request, session, or application scope.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try:

```
<spring:eval expression="@securityService.hasPermissionToAllArray(${data.regionsArray})" />
```

?

Note that there's no single quotes around `${data.regionsArray}`. I suspect you are getting a string because you are quoting the array.

Comment: Any `${}` expression in a JSP is resolved by the EL resolver regardless of the quotes.